# Button can not be deleted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button in a page, and I just found out it couldn't be commented out or deleted! It I did so, the whole page would show empty. (no error)

To clarify, I need the button and the toggled div. My purpose is to add some auth check to the button, and some super users could see it and use it but plain users could not. I just found out when I add auth check to hide the button from plain users, the plain users could see nothing but the header and footer. And I tried to comment out or delete the button, and found the whole page is just empty, as plain users see.

My first guess is some `div` or `form` or `table` have not been ended right, but it seems not.

My second guess is a `div` which supposed to be hidden when open the page has not been ended right but it is not, (This `div` will be toggled when hit the `button` I mentioned)

I've dug for hours, but could not find the real reason!

I attach the code here:
This is the head part. The only related part (I believe) is the `$('.add')click(function(){})`part.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".newsession").hide();
        $(".registration").hide();
        $(".showThisEdit").hide();

            $('.add').click(function() {
            $(".newsession").toggle(); 
            return false;
            });

            $('.editSes').click(function() {
                var showthis = $(this).attr("showthis");
                $("#show" + showthis).toggle();
                return false;
            }); 

            $(".show").click(function(){
                var show = $(this).attr("show");
                $("#" + show).toggle();
                return false;
            });
        });


    $(function() {
    $( ".datepickersession" ).datepicker();
    }); 


    </script>
```

Here is the body:

```
<!--Add New Sessions-->
<div class = 'container'>
<!--This BUTTON!!!-->
<button style ='color:blue' class = 'add' >Add New Sessions</button><br>

<div class = 'newsession' style = 'border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;'>
<div class = 'container'>
<form method = 'POST'>
<br>
<label>Term</label><input type = "text" name = "Term" value = "<?php echo $TermCheckRow['strm'];?>"><br>
<!--We have a lot of labels-->
<button type='submit' class = 'btn btn-primary' name = 'saveSession' value = 'saveSession'>Save</button>
<button type='submit' class = 'btn btn-danger' name = 'cancleaddSession' >Cancel</button>
</form><br>
</div>
</div><br>
<!--End of Add New Sessions-->

<!--Here we write into DB-->
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['saveSession'])){
    //our build in db connection functions
    }
?>

<!--And here there is a form-->
<form><table><thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table></form>

</div>
```

When I delete the button part

```
<button style ='color:blue' class = 'add' >Add New Sessions</button><br>
```

I got the empty page, I checked the source code. It is like this:
Head is the same.

This is the body: I have a very big form shown there, to save your time, I just delete those codes.

```
    <!--Add New Sessions-->
    <div class = 'container'>


    <div class = 'newsession' style = 'border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;'>
    <div class = 'container'>
    <form method = 'POST'>
    <br>
    <label>Term:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" name = "Term" value = "2159"><br>
    <label>Date:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" class = "datepickersession" name = "SessionDate"><br>
    <label>Time Begin:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" name = "TimeBegin" placeholder= "e.g.: 9:00am"><br>
    <label>Time End:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" name = "TimeEnd" placeholder= "e.g.: 9:00am"><br>
    <label>Cut Off Date:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" class = "datepickersession" name = "CutDate"><br>
    <label>Max Capacity:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" name = "MaxCap" value = "20"><br>
    <label>Location:&nbsp;</label><input type = "text" name = "Location">
    <br>
    <label>Hide:&nbsp;</label><input type = 'checkbox' name = "Hide"><br>
    <button type='submit' class = 'btn btn-primary' name = 'saveSession' value = 'saveSession'>Save</button>
    <button type='submit' class = 'btn btn-danger' name = 'cancleaddSession' >Cancel</button>
    </form><br>
    </div>
    </div><br>
    <!--End of Add New Sessions-->
<form class='form-horizontal' method='POST'>
</form></div></div>


</body> 
</html>
```

BUT the page is empty!

Could anyone have a look at this?
Many thanks!

Got some hints...

When generate the page, there is `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` build in already.

I so delete all newly added tags and update my codes here.

But, it still not works!

Comment: Wait, I myself found double </body></html>, what the heck? In my code there is only one </body></html>

Comment: Without the button the form will remain hidden unless you change the JS.

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem, but your HTML syntax is rife with errors - for example, all your <br> should be <br />, and all your input tags should be closed with /> instead of just >.

Comment: Jim, thank you for your input! but why if I keep the button there, everything is fine?

Comment: @Jim: Show me one single browser that would actually _care_ whether or not you used a `/` before the end of a self-closing element … (And calling that ”rife with errors” is nonsense too – you don’t even know if he’s using XHTML, and only that would _demand_ it.)

Comment: Thank you very much CBroe !! I don't think Jim meant to hurt me. haha..BTW, I am a girl. :-) I am not using XHTML, really.

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript in the `<head>` tag to read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".registration").hide();
    $(".showThisEdit").hide();

    $('.editSes').click(function() {
        var showthis = $(this).attr("showthis");
        $("#show" + showthis).toggle();
        return false;
    });

    $(".show").click(function() {
        var show = $(this).attr("show");
        $("#" + show).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});


$(function() {
    $(".datepickersession").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thank you hopkins-matt. It does not work. All divs supposed to be hidden are shown when load the page.

Comment: Hi. I still need the div to be toggled by clicking the button. I just don't understand why the button could not be commented out or deleted.

Comment: Check the new edit. I had shown two divs that did not need to be shown. However, you must show the `newsession` `<div>`. Without the button, your current JS will not show that `<div>`.

Comment: The reason you can not comment out or remove the button because it is responsible for showing the `newsession` `<div>`.

Comment: Thank you hopkins-matt! I could comment out an other button in the form which control the part:  $('.editSes').click(function() {
        var showthis = $(this).attr("showthis");
        $("#show" + showthis).toggle();
        return false;
    });

Comment: The button with class editSes are in the form, and the divs are in the same form. Why those buttons could be set auth check without crashing the page? I will edit my question to show you.

Comment: I tried your code it really works. I mean the page won't crash, but I do need to hide the div of newsession. I will think of another solution since the button has to be there...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you hopkins-matt. From your comments, I realize it is impossible to comment out a button which is linked to JS functions unless we comment out all the JS related functions. Although it is not ideal, I still solve the problem by adding a disabled invisible button for plain users. The code is here:

```
<?php if (Auth::hasPermissionIn(array('admin', 'super-user'))){ ?>
<button style ='color:blue' class = 'add' >Add New Sessions</button><br>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (Auth::hasPermissionIn(array('plain-user'))) { echo "<button class = 'add' style = 'border:none' disabled ></button>";} ?>
```

In this way, the button with class = 'add' is still there, but the plain user could neither see it or click it.

Thank you ALL!